# How do I select records from a table and order it by ID in a comma separated string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Let's say I have a table, with the following fields:

```
ID, NAME
=========
1, John
2, Peter
3, Jenny
4, Robert
5, Alan
```

And, I have a comma separated string with the ID from the table above. Let's say the string have the following value:

Sort_order = "3,5,4,1,2"

How do I select records from the table and order it by Sort_order?

The result set from the select should give records in the following order:

```
3, Jenny
5, Alan
4, Robert
1, John
2, Peter
```

Comment: What is the SQL Serve version?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 on my production server. And, Microsoft SQL Server 2014 on my development server.

Comment: [1, John] - single value? or 2 separate column?

Comment: This feels like it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - What are you actually trying to achieve that requires you to specify the sorting like that?

Comment: The sorting order is saved by a separate process in another table. So, after I have retrieved the sorting order, for example Sort_order = "3,5,4,1,2", I will then have to retrieve the records from the table and have the result set sort according to that sorting order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this script-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cef4282e27be86829c98cbab2920bb25)

```
--Consider this first parameter is you retrieved 
--order string from another table
DECLARE @order_ VARCHAR(MAX) = '3,5,4,1,2'

--Added Comma at the start and end of the order string
--So that id 1 and 11 do not conflict
DECLARE @order_new VARCHAR(MAX) = ','+@order_+','

SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(
    ','+CAST(id AS VARCHAR)+',
    ',@order_new,
    0
)
```

You can also ignore the second step of adding additional **Comma** to the order string and do it directly in the script as below which will return the same output-

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(
    ','+CAST(id AS VARCHAR)+',',
    ','+@order_+',',
    0
)
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: I am new to this. Is the following hard coded in a store procedure?

;with your_table(id, name)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'John' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Peter' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Jenny' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Robert' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'Alan'
)

Comment: That's just for example. Ignore that and the final query I have edited for you now. That ;with... was just for creating the virtual table with your data.

Comment: You can also you a CASE in the ORDER BY instaed of CHARINDEX or in earlier version use the CHOOSE integrated function:ORDER BY CHOOSE(ID, 3,5,4,1,2)